# How to use Django function based view to update a model?

Tags: django, django-views

I used a class based view to update a user profile using this code

```
class EditProfileViewClass(generic.UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ['bio', 'profile pic']
    template_name = 'users/update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

path('profile/<int:pk>/update', EditProfileViewClass.as_view(), name="profile"),

<a href="{% url 'profile' user.id %}">Your Profile</a>
```

the issue right now is, Instead of having the url like the one above, I want it to be like

`path('profile/<str:username>/update', EditProfileViewClass.as_view(), name="profile"),`

but unfortunately I get an attribute error saying:

`Generic detail view EditProfileView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.`

So I tried making a function based view so I can get the "username" from the url, doing that didn't allow me to get the form I needed to update the specific username.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Show your function based view

Comment: Can you share your `UserProfile` model? Does it have a `username` field, or is it linked to the user model?

Comment: @Rvector def EditProfileViewFunction(request, username,*args, **kwargs):
    form = UpdateProfileForm
    return render(request, 'registration/updateprofile.html', {"form":form, "username":username})

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it's connected with the user in a ForeignKey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `EditProfileViewClass` view you can add `pk_url_kwarg` or `slug_url_kwarg`.

```
class EditProfileViewClass(UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ['bio', 'profile pic']
    template_name = 'users/update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    pk_url_kwarg = 'username'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! I got couple of questions. First, Can you show me how to write it using function based view? and Second what will my url look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class-based view, you only need to update the the `slug_field` (which determines on what should be used), and the `slug_url_kwargs`:

```
class EditProfileViewClass(UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ['bio', 'profile_pic']
    template_name = 'users/update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    slug_field = 'user__username'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'
```

This will thus take the `username` parameter of the URL, and it will filter the queryset to only retrieve a `UserProfile` that is linked to a `user` with that `username`.

Comment: @MicahHaile: which of the two, the first answer uses `pk_url_kwarg` and `slug_url_kwarg`, whereas the second uses `slug_field` and `slug_url_kwarg`